# Magento2: Issue with photo in basket for configurable product

Tags: magento2, checkout

Always, in other magento stores I add only one photo for main configurable product without photo for sizes and work everything as should.

Now when I add in this way (without photo for sizes):
[image]

then missing photo in basket:
[image]

I need to add in this way to show photo in basket (photo for main and for all sizes).
[image]

any solution?